# Spring: @PostConstruct is not called on maven tests, but works fine if test is running in IDEA

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

The problem is that the `@PostConstruct` method is not invoked during maven tests, but works fine if I run these tests in IDEA.

Why is it not invoked during maven tests and how do I fix this?

My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class, DBConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SecurityTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void openLibraryPage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/books")
                .with(httpBasic("admin", "admin")))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
    }

}
```

The class, that contains `@PostConstruct` *(this configuration works fine and beans in this class are initialized both in maven tests and in idea tests, it's just the @PostConstruct method is not being invoked in maven tests for some reason)*

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("test.task")
public class DBConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(DBConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeDatabase() {
        .. some code ..
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:h2:mem:test-task;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE", "sa", "");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

and my **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test.task</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**# UPDATE 1**

Added `DBConfig.class` to `@ContextConfiguration`, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem and for me it was because the following dependency was not on the classpath:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Are IntelliJ and Maven using the same Java Version? Maybe IntelliJ is using Java < 9, that's why it works and Maven uses Java >= 9 and therefore needs the dependency i mentioned.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48383137)

Comment: Versions were the same (java 8) but this helped anyway

Answer (score 1):

While starting the test, you are just loading the `AppConfig` into the context. And, it seems like `DBConfig` is not loaded in the context, which is the reason for `initializeDatabase` method not getting invoked.

To make it work, `DBConfig` has to be loaded,

> @ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class, DBConfig.class})

Comment: I tried it, but nothing changed.
Besides, beans from `DBConfig` seem to be initializing fine without adding `DBConfig.class` to `@ContextConfiguration`

Comment: @SpringBootTest(classes = {AppConfig.class, DBConfig.class}). Can you please try this?

Comment: I did try this, but it did not change anything